# Do mobs spawn in the air?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm about to bring my house to perfection by bringing the light-level at minimum 8.

However. In some areas of my house, when I jump, I see that there is a light level of 7. Can a mob spawn there or won't they spawn "in the air"? Means: Is a light level of 8 everywhere where you can stand enough to get rid of spawning mobs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "spawn". (Your answer is "Yes" and "No".)

**If a monster is spawned from a Monster Spawner, then:**
Yes it can, as Monster Spawners will always create a mob near the spawner at intervals when the conditions around the Spawner are correct *even if there is no available block to spawn on*, as light is calculated in 3D space.

**However, if the monster is spawned naturally then:**
No, it does not. Monsters only spawn naturally on [solid](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Solid_block), non-[transparent](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Opacity) blocks at light level 7 or below. The light level at other points above or to the side of the solid block are not taken into account.

Comment: Addition: "Not full" blocks like slabs (only if you use an odd amount. putting 2 so that a full block exists, won't work) or pressure plates, torches, etc will prevent mob spawning as well.